# What are the readline word separators?

Tags: bash, readline

When I delete a "word" in Bash, it will stop at certain characters like `_` and `/`. For example, if I type

```
/foo/bar
```

and activate `backward-kill-word` (typically mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and/or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>), the remaining text is

```
/foo/
```

. This does *not* correspond to `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` or [`readline`'s `rl_completer_word_break_characters`](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/readline-4.1/html_node/readline_44.html). How can I detect (preferably in a running system, rather than the defaults in the code, since they presumably can be overridden) which characters are used to determine word breaks?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The bash documentation states:

> ```
> backward-kill-word (M-Rubout)
> ```
>
> Kill  the  word  behind  point.   Word  boundaries  are the same as those used by backward-word.

And

> ```
> backward-word (M-b)
> ```
>
> Move back to the start of the current or previous word.  Words are composed of alphanumeric characters (letters and digits).

The handling of `backward-word` in Bash 4.2 is done in the bundled libreadline code ([`text.c:rl_backward_word`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/text.c?id=495aee441b75276e38c75694ccb455bb6463fdb9#n509)). The word break is based on [`rl_alphabetic`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/util.c?id=495aee441b75276e38c75694ccb455bb6463fdb9#n71), which itself relies on the [`isalnum`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isalnum.html) function. This is locale-dependent, but not configurable directly in bash.

Note that Bash 4.0 introduced another "word" type with the `shell-forward-word` and `shell-backward-word` actions (and kill equivalents). These break only on shell meta-characters (`()<>;&|"`) and blanks (possibly locale dependant via `isblank`), handled in the main bash code (`bashline.c`).

Comment: Good references, but that's rather vague. Do they mean `[^A-Za-z0-9]`, `[^[:alnum:]]` (localization dependent) or something else?

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's configurable with locales (the `alnum` character class) though that would affect other applications as well.

Comment: Ok, was looking at the wrong place in the code (shell-backward-*)... The split is based on `isalnum`, so indeed locale-dependent and equivalent to your second version, @l0b0.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas: I meant that it couldn't be configured via bash options, rephrased that bit.