# Command line "delete last word" misbehaving

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

In my zsh environment, when I try to delete last word on command line using either `Ctrl + W` or `Opt + Delete`, it is always misbehaving, eg

```
# start with this line below
pg_ctl --help

# Trying to delete last word with either Ctrl + W or Opt + Delete, I am hoping to get
pg_ctl
# instead I got
pg_ctl --

# Trying to delete last word again with either Ctrl + W or Opt + Delete, I'm hoping to get
pg_ctl
# but instead I got
pg_
```

It is so frustrating that I have to post here to seek help. Have you guys seen this and know how to fix it?

I'm running macOS Monterey, iTerms and oh-myzsh. I just tested. This happens in my bash environment too.

Thanks

Comment: Update: `Ctrl + W` works correctly on my bash, but `Opt + Delete` is the same bad as zsh

Comment: Update: I primarily use iTerm2. I just tested on Terminal and see the same. So it's not related to iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

You and the shell seem to have different ideas on which characters are parts of a word and which aren't.

For `zsh`, you should read [chapter 4.3.4: *Words, Regions and Marks*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide04.html#l87) of the `zsh` User Guide. Depending on which editing mode you're using, you might be able to get what you want by manipulating the `$WORDCHARS` variable (it contains a list of non-alphanumeric characters that should also be considered parts of a word).

(Disclaimer: I don't know much about current versions of `zsh` and especially not of `oh-my-zsh`. My job takes me to many systems, often stripped-down to the minimum required, some with fancy configurations; so I've got used to working with "plain vanilla" shell configuration. I have a fairly minimal set of shell customizations I might set up on systems I visit often, but I can live without them if necessary; I understand many professional sysadmins generally end up with shell configurations like that eventually.)

For `bash`, if your "delete last word" keystroke is associated to `readline` library function `backward-kill-word` (as by default), it considers only letters and numbers as word components; any other characters will separate words from each other.

In `bash` version 4.0 and newer, there should be an alternative `readline` function named `shell-backward-kill-word`, which might suit your needs better.[See this question for more details.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78990/258991)